# How to get results from python unit tests in Django using custom settings

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am trying to generate a report from the unit tests in Django.
For running the tests and retrieving the results I am using a custom TestResult class, which works fine:

```
results = TestResult()
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suites = loader.discover('test_folder')
for suite in suites:
    suite(results)
```

My only issue is that I can't override the settings file to use in memory database. I decorated my test cases with **override_settings** from **django.test**, which works for me only in the command line. When I run it using the loader it uses the my_app.settings file, however, it looks like it is overridden:

```
>>> from django.conf import settings   
>>> settings.DATABASES   
{'default': {'TEST_CHARSET': 'UTF8', 'NAME': ':memory:', 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'TEST_NAME': ':memory:'}}
```

I also created my own override_settings file to override any function in my project and the result is the same. I tried to override the **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE** in os.environ, but still having the same issue. Maybe I am missing some django.setup() function to load the settings file again.

I want to be able to:

- get results from the unit tests
- use custom settings
- load specific test module (just like with the **loader.discover(start_dir)**)

TestCase example:

```
from rest_framework import status  
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase  

class TestCase(APITestCase):  
    fixtures = ('dump',)
    url = '/api/post'

    def test_post(self):
         # returns post from existing database not from fixture
         post = Post.objects.get(pk=3)
         data = {
            'name': 'test',
            'post': post.content
        }
        response = self.client.post(self.url + '/1', data=data)
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Using:

- Python 3.4
- Django 1.9

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using command `./manage.py test`, then you could just parse the commandline argument and see if it's a `test`, then have an `if` statement in your `settings.py`:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3'
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not using the command line. I want to display the results as an HTML report and run the tests in my view.

Comment: That doesn't make much sense, you can't be running the project while letting your project test itself, because your one project can't be connecting to production database and test database at the same time. You should always create a separate procedure to test your code.

Comment: Good point. Thanks. Finally I get the test results using the call_command function.